# php extension compiles with newer API version than my PHP

Tags: php-extension

This is driving me nuts : I'm trying to compile a php extension for a library (www.phah.org), which compiles fine, but when I try to enable load it with php, I have the following warning (this is actually the output of make test):

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: pHash: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20100525
PHP    compiled with module API=20090626
```

The confusing thing is when i do phpize before compiling, it shows the right API version :

```
$ phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
```

But it is still compiled with 20100525 (php 5.4) instead of 220090626 (php 5.3).
I spent quite some time searching, but I only found ppl having the opposite problem (extension compiling for an older version of php).

Any hints?

Comment: And here is the list of my installed php packages:

php-pear          5.3.10-1ubuntu3.9,
php5              5.3.10-1ubuntu3.9,
  php5-cli          5.3.10-1ubuntu3.9,
  php5-common       5.3.10-1ubuntu3.9,
  php5-curl         5.3.10-1ubuntu3.9, 
  php5-dev          5.3.10-1ubuntu3.9,
  php5-fpm          5.3.10-1ubuntu3.9,
  php5-gd           5.3.10-1ubuntu3.9,
  php5-mcrypt       5.3.5-0ubuntu1,    
  php5-mysql        5.3.10-1ubuntu3.9

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it out : instead of using the php bindings shipped with 0.9.6 sources, you can use either the 0.9.4 version from here https://github.com/sdepold/pHash, or this version as it is forked from 0.9.6, https://github.com/Alexis2004/php-phash
Both compile just fine without the API version problem. looks like it doesn't come from Zend apparently.

Comment: I am still getting the following error with https://github.com/Alexis2004/php-phash: 

Notice: Undefined variable: linedef in /usr/share/php/CodeGen/PECL/Element/Function.php on line 1345
[...]
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
[...]
checking for pHash.h... yes
checking audiophash.h usability... yes
checking audiophash.h presence... yes
checking for audiophash.h... yes
checking for ph_texthash in -lpHash... no
configure: error: wrong pHash lib version or lib not found